# Dialogflow agent responses are intermittently failing

Tags: twilio-api, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have a Dialogflow agent integrated with Twillio. Before the integration model change, all agent responses came smoothly. Since I changed the integration method following the instructions published by Dialogflow, the agent's responses fail intermittently generating the message 14103-Invalid Body in Twilio:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Message/>
</Response>
```

The agent's response comes to Twilio in some cases but not in others. I observe this behavior repeating the same intent several times in the agent.

The fullfillment webhook was developed in NodeJs and is deployed in a different Google Cloud project than the Agent.

I did try two methods:

- Direct method

```
 if (estCuenta.msg == 'OK') {
            console.log('trace 1');
            await validaDisclaimer(`${cedula}`);
            if (!disclaimerOk) {
                console.log('trace 2');
                agent.context.set({ 'name': 'esperadisclaimer-followup', 'lifespan': 1 });
                agent.add('Some message')
                sendWhatsAppMedia('https://someFile.pdf?alt=media&token=18ebc493-27fc-4c46-96eb-e80f05716acc',
                                'someFileDescription');
            }
```

- Function method

```
 if (estCuenta.msg == 'OK') {
            console.log('trace 1');
            await validaDisclaimer(`${cedula}`);
            if (!disclaimerOk) {
                console.log('trace 2');
                agent.context.set({ 'name': 'esperadisclaimer-followup', 'lifespan': 1 });
                await sendAgentResponse(agent, 'Some message')
                sendWhatsAppMedia('https://someFile.pdf?alt=media&token=18ebc493-27fc-4c46-96eb-e80f05716acc',
                                'someFileDescription');
            }
```

... the funtion that try to send response to Dialogflow agent

```
     function sendAgentResponse(agent, message) {
        const promise = new Promise(resolve => {
    
            // logic goes here
    
            resolve(agent.add(message));
        });
        return promise;
    }
```

Comment: can you provide more data and some sample fulfillment code. Also provide the raw data from the history where the event fails.

Comment: Thank you for you response. I did try two methods:
- Direct method

Comment: `code`
 if (estCuenta.msg == 'OK') {
            console.log('trace 1');
            await validaDisclaimer(`${cedula}`);
            if (!disclaimerOk) {
                console.log('trace 2');
                agent.context.set({ 'name': 'esperadisclaimer-followup', 'lifespan': 1 });
                agent.add('Some message')
                sendWhatsAppMedia('https://someFile.pdf?alt=media&token=18ebc493-27fc-4c46-96eb-e80f05716acc',
                                'someFileDescription');
            }
`code`

Comment: - Function method
`code`
 if (estCuenta.msg == 'OK') {
            console.log('trace 1');
            await validaDisclaimer(`${cedula}`);
            if (!disclaimerOk) {
                console.log('trace 2');
                agent.context.set({ 'name': 'esperadisclaimer-followup', 'lifespan': 1 });
                await sendAgentResponse(agent, 'Some message')
                sendWhatsAppMedia('https://someFile.pdf?alt=media&token=18ebc493-27fc-4c46-96eb-e80f05716acc',
                                'someFileDescription');
            }
`code`

Comment: this is the function that try to send response to Dialogflow in the second method:
`code`
     function sendAgentResponse(agent, message) {
        const promise = new Promise(resolve => {
    
            // logic goes here
    
            resolve(agent.add(message));
        });
        return promise;
    }
`code`